# Split output to multiple files in Hive

Tags: sql, csv, hive, sftp, file-transfer

I want to split SQL results in Hive per one attribute and transfer these files to sFTP.

Current code does the extract, however without both requirments.
Within the SQL results I have few attributes. One of them - USER_ID - must serve as a cut-off point. Once new ID is recognized - new file must be created.

EDIT - added timestamp

`beeline -u jdbc:hive2:<MYHOST> -n <USER> -p <PASSWORD> --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -f <SQL FILE> > result_+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.csv`

The goal is to split one file (beeline output) into multiple csv files per `USER_ID` in sFTP location.

Beeline script result:

`USER | ATTR1 | ATTR2
 ID1    val     val
 ID2    val     val
 ID2    val     val`

After transformation expected result:

`USER | ATTR1 | ATTR2
 ID1    val     val`

`USER | ATTR1 | ATTR2
 ID2    val     val
 ID2    val     val`

Comment: So, your code generates only one file?

Comment: @F.Lazarescu - exactly

Comment: And you don’t want to execute the code twice (using a different filter on the select statement?). It seems that you cannot write the beeline command to generate two files ..

Comment: I could copy the SQL code with different filter (by USER_ID) and use above script. That solution requires more script files to be produced however. The concept is to run one SQL in beeline and later split that file with power shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @David C. Rankin

[Split CSV file in bash into multiple files based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354409/split-csv-file-in-bash-into-multiple-files-based-on-condition)

```
     awk -v field=a -v n=1 -v dt=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    'FS=","; 
     FNR == 1 {hdg=$0; next} a != $1 {a = $1; name=a"_file_"dt".csv"; n++;
     print hdg >name} 
     {print $0 > name}' 
     sample_file.csv
```