# Split CSV file in bash into multiple files based on condition

Tags: linux, bash, csv

My csv file has multiple rows of data and I want to split it into multiple files based on one attribute.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2:<MYHOST> -n <USER> -p <PASSWORD> --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -f <SQL FILE> > result_+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.csv
```

SQL code with `ORDER BY ID` is triggered from beeline which creates single CSV.

```
cat sql.csv
"attr;attr;ID;attr"
"data;data;XXXX;date"
"data;data;XXXX;date"
"data;data;YYYYY;date"
"data;data;YYYYY;date"
"data;data;BBBBB;date"
"data;data;BBBBB;date"
```

Desired result is to split once new `ID` is recognised and use that `ID` in filename.

`file_1_ID_XXXX_+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`:

```
attr   attr    ID  attr
data    data    XXXX    date
data    data    XXXX    date
```

`file_2_ID_YYYYY_+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`:

```
attr   attr    ID  attr
data    data    YYYYY   date
data    data    YYYYY   date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can take the csv file produced by sql and then split that into the 3 files you show simply by using a few variables, string concatenation and then by redirecting to the output files, e.g.

```
awk -v field=a -v n=1 -v dt=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') '
    FNR == 1 {hdg=$0; next}
    a != $3 {a = $3; name="file_"n"_ID_"a"_"dt; n++; print hdg > name}
    {print $0 > name}
' sqldata
```

**Example Input File**

Where your `sqldata` file contains:

```
$ cat sqldata
attr    attr    ID  attr
data    data    XXXX    date
data    data    XXXX    date
data    data    YYYYY   date
data    data    YYYYY   date
data    data    BBBBB   date
data    data    BBBBB   date
```

**Example Use/Output Files**

Simply copying and middle-mouse pasting awk script into the terminal with the correct filename to read would produce the following three output files:

```
$ cat file_1_ID_XXXX_20190805_033514
attr    attr    ID  attr
data    data    XXXX    date
data    data    XXXX    date

$ cat file_2_ID_YYYYY_20190805_033514
attr    attr    ID  attr
data    data    YYYYY   date
data    data    YYYYY   date

$ cat file_3_ID_BBBBB_20190805_033514
attr    attr    ID  attr
data    data    BBBBB   date
data    data    BBBBB   date
```

Look things over and let me know if this is what you intended. If not, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: I changed `a != $3 {a = $3` to `a != $1 {a = $1` in case `ID` was first column but data gets split by different attribute.

Comment: Unless you have different data, you column 1 just contains the heading `attr` and then the remaining records all contain `data` which will not do what you ask?

Comment: I forgot to mention that CSV file is comma delimited, not in a tabular form. CurrentIy I see odd behaviour (data gets split but completely different attribute which is ` ` seperated date). Probably because of comma delimited seperator `,`

Comment: When I have one attribue `ID` in my CSV file everything works ok. When I add more attributes the script doesn't parse the data into columns but sees each rows as if it was concatenated.

Comment: Awesome. good job for getting that sorted. Each little victory is one more aspect of `awk` learned. Once you get over the initial cryptic look, `awk` really isn't bad at all to work with.